# Is it possible to make a connection to a Flash instance in the browser from an AIR app?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, localconnection

Is it possible and how would I make a connection to a Flash instance in the browser from an AIR app running on the desktop?

I'm opening up a browser window to a specific web page where I can add a Flash player instance. I then want to communicate with the browser instance in a one way communication.

Example from AIR app:

1. var connection = connectToBrowserFlashInstance()
2. connection.send("updated");

Example code from Flash instance:

1. addEventListener("messages", messageHandler);
2. if (message=="updated") then do something

Comment: Haven't developer for the Flash platform in years, but if I recall this is possible with LocalConnection.

Comment: LocalConnection is the way to go, google search it.... the key is the allowDomain wildcarding ("*") and using a connection name starting with an underscore...

Comment: Also you may want to use the `Socket` connection between them. Especially in case you have some large data to pass, as the aforementioned LocalConnection has some message size limitation^ as far as i remember